# how to add the external hdd to bios boot order

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, external-hard-drive

I bought a haier laptop y11b, which has a 29GB ssd and 500 Gb Hdd (St500Ito 12-IDG142usb device) internaly installed on it by default.
the operating system is installed on ssd that is windows 10 so it boots from the ssd. 
now I wanted to install windows 10 on the 500GB external hdd. so I convert this hdd to mbr,then convert it into small partitions and installed windows 10 on D partition.
now I am trying to boot from this hdd but bios is not even showing it in the priority order or boot options list.

so basically I want to ask...

1: how to add this hdd to bios boot order?? (so it can be selected easily)
2: how to install all of my apps on this hdd by default,  without any registery edits(as it may result in malfunctioning of few applications).

please check out these screen shots of device manager and disk management..
[image: disk managment]
[image: device manager]

thanks...

Comment: Your screenshots do not show the external HDD. Name some apps you use, I may give the procedure to use apps in external drives (procedures may vary to softwares).

Comment: i bought the a new laptop and the external hdd was internally installed on it, I have not manually attach it, so I can't take the screen shots of it. and I use softwares like ms office, visual studio,dream viewer, adobe photoshop, corel draw, and games like delta force,need for speed etc...